# scikit-learn SGDClassifier object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, azure-machine-learning-service

I am just trying out training a simple logistic regression model using SGD in python in Azure ML, but when I run the code it keep getting an error. What is more confusing is that the error shows up in Epoch 8  only and not in any of the epochs. I ll appreciate if anyone and can let me know why I would get an error like this and how to avoid it. I have included the code and error below.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
    #Import data
    cadd_dir = '.\\Script Bundle\\theano\\data\\'
    ClinVar_ESP_dir = '.\\Script Bundle\\theano\\data\\'
    #load data    
    X_tr = numpy.load(os.path.join(cadd_dir, 'training.X.npz'))
    X_tr = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((X_tr['data'], X_tr['indices'], X_tr['indptr']), shape=X_tr['shape'])
    y_tr = numpy.load(os.path.join(cadd_dir, 'training.y.npy'))
    #Train model
    print('Train SGD Logistic Regression')
    alpha = 1e-2
    clf = SGDClassifier(loss="log", penalty='l2', alpha=alpha, random_state=None, shuffle=False, n_iter=10, verbose=1, n_jobs=1)
    clf.fit(X_tr, y_tr)




#Error
"[Information]         -- Epoch 7
[Information]         Norm: 0.40, NNZs: 641, Bias: 0.000623, T: 186214000, Avg. loss: 0.670200
[Information]         Total training time: 43.97 seconds.

[Information]         -- Epoch 8
[Error]         Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
[Error]           File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 211, in batch
[Error]             xdrutils.XDRUtils.DataFrameToRFile(outlist[i], outfiles[i], True)
[Error]           File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrutils.py", line 51, in DataFrameToRFile
[Error]             attributes = XDRBridge.DataFrameToRObject(dataframe)
[Error]           File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrbridge.py", line 40, in DataFrameToRObject
[Error]             if (len(dataframe) == 1 and type(dataframe[0]) is pd.DataFrame):
[Error]         TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
[Information]         Norm: 0.40, NNZs: 641, Bias: 0.000623, T: 212816000, Avg. loss: 0.669797
[Information]         Total training time: 50.21 seconds.

[Information]         -- Epoch 9
[Information]         Norm: 0.40, NNZs: 641, Bias: 0.000622, T: 239418000, Avg. loss: 0.669482
[Information]         Total training time: 56.46 seconds."
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is creating both regular output ("[Information]") and error messages ("[Error]"), but Azure ML Studio is only built to show one output log, so both types of messages have been written to the same file. Adding to the confusion, each type of message experienced different delays when being written to the log. This explains why your error messages are bracketed with information messages about Epoch 8 of training, even though the two are unrelated.

The errors were thrown by the functions which are supposed to export the results of your Python script when the module finishes running. To run properly in Azure ML, your code needs to be wrapped in a function named `azureml_main()` (which is included as a template in new Execute Python Script modules). `azureml_main()` needs to return a `pandas` `DataFrame`. I'm not sure what you want to return since your code simply fits a model, but the following may help:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
import numpy
import scipy
import pandas as pd

cadd_dir = '.\\Script Bundle\\theano\\data\\'
ClinVar_ESP_dir = '.\\Script Bundle\\theano\\data\\'

def azureml_main(input_df1 = None, input_df2 = None):
    #load data    
    X_tr = numpy.load(os.path.join(cadd_dir, 'training.X.npz'))
    X_tr = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((X_tr['data'], X_tr['indices'], X_tr['indptr']), shape=X_tr['shape'])
    y_tr = numpy.load(os.path.join(cadd_dir, 'training.y.npy'))
    #Train model
    print('Train SGD Logistic Regression')
    alpha = 1e-2
    clf = SGDClassifier(loss="log", penalty='l2', alpha=alpha, random_state=None, shuffle=False, n_iter=10, verbose=1, n_jobs=1)
    clf.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
    return(pd.DataFrame([]))
```

P.S. Are you working with Jenn/Nicolo from MSR on variant effect prediction? If not you should ping them